# Vercel Deployment Error 404 with my HTML5 and CSS project

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, vercel

I´m having a problem with vercel. I'm done trying everything.

I tried to deploy, multiple times, my node app with express and nothing works, I always get:

" 404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND "

Here's my index.js:

```
const exp = require('constants');
const express = require('express');
const res = require('express/lib/response');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

//express server port

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () =>{
 console.log("Server status: Online.")
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/index.html"));
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/register.html"));
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/views/login.html"));
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
```

and my vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./app.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],

    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried deleting node_modules, changing "app.js" to "index.js", almost everything, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can change index.js to app.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).